# Remove escaped characters

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Okay, so say I have some user input that selects something from a mysql database.

I want to be safe from mysql injection so in order to do so I'd use the mysql_real_escape_string() function. But after that, I want the quote or whatever is bad from my string out of the variable completely.

EXAMPLE- :

```
my title variable = Herp'
escape with mysql_real_escape_string()....
then my variable = Herp\'
```

Now, I want the bad quote out of there. So, I want to remove the backslash & character after the backslash.. so it looks like 'Herp'.

How would I do that?

sorry if that's confusing.

Comment: So, you want to generally remove apostrophes from your input? And characters are never "bad". You either want them or you don't. If you escape them you have nothing to fear from them.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to filter out quotes instead of escaping them, simply try

```
$myTitleVar = str_replace(array("'", '"'), '', $myTitleVar);
```

Before inserting it into the DB, I'd still recommend running it through `mysql_real_escape_string()` or even better, use PDO and parameter binding.

Answer (score 0):

use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/es/function.stripslashes.php)

but I would dig why that is happening. Check your [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) settings. For safety reasons is it good to have then set to `off`

Comment: that only gets rid of the slash, not the extra character... if i run that it basicly undoes mysql_real_escape_string();